# NgRX 8 is not working in my Angular 8 with a failure: 'toJSON failed on Type'

Tags: angular8, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have been trying since yesterday to add the new NgRX 8 to my Angular application. But I am stuck on one thing and I don't know what the problem is.

I have tried to build a very simple example for movies:

```
export class Movie {
   public id: number;
   public name: string;
   constructor() {}
}
```

My actions are:

```
export const getAll = createAction('[Movies Page] Load Movies');
export const getAllSuccess = createAction('[Movies Page] Load Movies Success', props<{ payload: Movie[] }>());
export const getAllFail = createAction('[Movies Page] Load Movies Fail', props<{ error: any }>());
```

And my effect is:

```
@Injectable()
export class MovieEffects {
   constructor(private actions$: Actions) {
   }

   loadMovies$ = createEffect(() =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
         ofType(getAll),
         switchMap(() =>
            of([movies_array]).pipe(
               map(result => getAllSuccess({ payload: result })),
               catchError(error => of(getAllFail({ error })))
            )
         )
      )
   );
}
```

I have added all of action cases to my reducer:

```
export interface AppState<T> {
   list: T[];
   isNull: boolean;
   count: number;
   type: StateType;
}

export const initialState: AppState<Movie> = {
   type: StateType.Loading,
   isNull: true,
   count: 0,
   list: new Array<Movie>()
};

const movieRed = createReducer(
   initialState,
   on(MovieActionTypes.getAll, state => ({
      ...state,
      type: StateType.Loading
   })),
   on(MovieActionTypes.getAllSuccess, (state: AppState<Movie>, action) => ({
      ...state,
      type: StateType.Loaded,
      isNull: action.payload == null,
      count: action.payload != null ? action.payload.length : 0,
      list: action.payload
   })),
   on(MovieActionTypes.getAllFail, state => ({
      ...state,
      type: StateType.Error
   }))
);

export function movieReducer(state: AppState<Movie> = initialState, action) {
   return movieRed(state, action);
}
```

And added the effects forRoot and reducers forRoot in my module.

Everything works fine. But when I am trying to read the state using:

```
this.movies$ = store.pipe(select('list'));
```

I result is always undefined and I see this message in my DevTool

[image]

I have no idea where the problem is. I have tried many solutions, none has worked for me.
Does anybody know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. I have missed defining the AppState.

```
export interface AppState {
   movieReducer: ReducerState<Movie>;
}
```

and in the module:

```
StoreModule.forFeature('movieReducer', movieReducer),
```